# How to compare values with a reference table in R?

Tags: r, merge

I have following 2 dataframes. The 'ddf' has age and wt values of group while 'refdf' is reference table for lower and upper limit of wt for different ages.

```
ddf =  read.csv(text="
                    age, wt
                    10,26
                    9,21
                    8,28
                    6,16
                    7,20
                    11,24",header=T)

refdf =  read.csv(text="
                    age,lower,upper
                    5, 10, 14
                    6, 11, 13
                    7, 13, 15
                    8, 14, 18
                    9, 16, 21
                    10, 17, 22
                    11, 19, 25
                    12, 22, 29",header=T)
```

I need to have another column called 'result' in ddf which should have a value of -1,1 or 0 depending on the wt being <= lower, >=upper or between lower & upper of refdf for the corresponding age value.

I tried following code but it does not work:

```
ddf$result = ifelse(refdf[age<=lower,],-1, ifelse(refdf[age>=upper,],1,0))
Error in `[.data.frame`(refdf, age <= lower, ) : object 'lower' not found
```

How can I accompalish this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assomplish this by first finding the correct category with `match`, then doing the comparisons and converting them to numeric values.

```
m <- match(ddf$age, refdf$age)
ddf$result <- (refdf$lower[m] > ddf$wt) *(-1) + 
    (ddf$wt > refdf$upper[m])*1

# 1  10 26      1
# 2   9 21      1
# 3   8 28      1
# 4   6 16      1
# 5   7 20      1
# 6  12 18     -1
# 7  11 24      0
```

(I added in an underweight individual) You can take out the `=` part of the inequalities if you want weights on the boundaries to be in the OK zone.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted. I will just make sure it is working well with my data and then accept the answer.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, if the case is more than 3 intervals. What you will suggest? example we have lower, middle and upper columns. Thanks.

Comment: @BeginneR: you can combine ifelse statements: ddf$result <- ifelse(ddf$wt < refdf$lower[m], -1,ifelse(ddf$wt>refdf$upper[m], 2,ifelse(ddf$wt>refdf$middle[m],1,0)))

Comment: @BeginneR This method (multiplying by the number you want returned) will work as long as all of your comparisons are mutually exclusive (ie only one is true at a time).