# How to combine value with with a reference table in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

This question is very similar to these two posts: [How to compare values with a reference table in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925702/how-to-compare-values-with-a-reference-table-in-r)
and [Combine Table with reference to another table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785533/combine-table-with-reference-to-another-table-in-r) . However, mine is more complicated:

I have two data frames:

```
> df1
             name value1 value2
1  applefromJapan      2      8
2 applesfromJapan      3      9
3  applenotfromUS      4     10
4  pearsgoxxJapan      5     11
5  bananaxxeeChina     6     12

> df2
                  name value1 value2
1       applefromJapan     33      1
2 watermeleonnotfromUS     34      2
3      applesfromJapan     35      3
4        pearfromChina     36      4
5        pearfromphina     37      5 # only one letter different will not cause problem
```

and a reference table:

```
> ref.df
  fruit country             name seller
1   1:5   10:14       appleJapan   John
2   1:5   10:14       pearsJapan   Mike
3   1:6   11:15      applesJapan Nicole
4   1:6   11:12         bananaUS    Amy
5   1:4    9:13        pearChina  Jenny
6   1:5   13:14          appleUS   Mark
7  1:10   18:22 watermeleonchina  James
```

The reference table works as the following:
the `name` column in the `ref.df` contains the full name, where `df1`(`df2`) can obtain this name by trimming its `name` column according to the `fruit` and `country` column.

My desire output table is:

```
#output
         name   value1 value2 value3 value4
1  appleJapan      2      8     33     1 # ended up using the name from the ref.df
2 applesJapan      3      9     34     2 # merge df1 and df2
3  appleUS         4     10     NA     NA # replacing NA for not exist values
4  pearsJapan      5     11     NA     NA
5 watermeleonUS    NA    NA     34     2
6 pearChina        NA    NA     73     9 # name with only one letter difference consider as typo, so we will just sum the values up.
# bananaxxeeChina is not here because it does not referenced by the ref.df
```

*There are thousands of row in the real dataset (~12000 rows on average in each of the 22 dfs, ~ 200 rows in the ref.df), this is only the first couple rows (with some alternation). So I think it is better to compare each df to the ref.df, then combine the df2? But how can i achieve this?

Codes for producing data:
https://codeshare.io/2p179V

Comment: You may need `merge` or join `full_join(df1, df2, by = 'name')`

Comment: I tried doing that but that creates many extra rows (because there are not many same name between dfs). So I am trying to do the referencing first, then summing up the values in the dfs, and finally merge the dfs.

Comment: In the reference dataset, it seems to be related to substring of each name.  So, you want to substring the 'name' column based on that?

Comment: @akrun yes, but the problem is that, for each name, there are different fruit and country (splitting position).

Comment: For the first element, what does 10:14 signify in `appleJapan`  it seems to be not the 10th position as there are only 10 characters in that

Comment: @akrun the `fruit` and `country` refers to the dfs, so for example, if you do substring on `1:5,10:14` on the df1 `name -applefromJapan`, you will get `appleJapan`

Comment: I think a better option may be to have all stop words ie. from, 'not' etc and remove it i..e `df1 %>% mutate(name = str_remove_all(name, 'from|not|goxx|xxee')) %>% full_join(df2 %>% mutate(name = str_remove_all(name, 'from|not|goxx|xxee')), by = 'name')`

Comment: @akrun that's a good idea. but it only works for this example, my dataset (which is basically more rows of the example) contains way more stop words, like `oiuy|dsgr|nbve` ...etc

Comment: Just a doubt.  Is there any typos `watermeleonchina` .  All others seems to be having country name starting with uppercase and meleon should be melon.  If we have a pattern in the way it was showed in ref.df, it could be split up, but the issue is that your substring in the ref is based on the columns in other dataset

Comment: it should be watermeleon not melon lol, but it is lowercase china

Comment: Also, entries like `watermeleonnotfromUS` can be difficult to match if we go by the literal meaning not from

Comment: I think the main problem is that this dataset contains too many rows (so it's hard to find a pattern) and there are typos in them! That's why sometimes the country name may start with lowercase, non-sense stop string...etc

Comment: @akrun so my thinking is to compare to the ref.df first to "fix" all the typos, because we know that the ref.df must be right

Comment: What would be the correspoinding value in 'ref.df' for watermeleonnotfromUS.  This may require fuzzy join with stringdist etc, but it may also fail in certain cases

Comment: @akrun if it doesn't exist in the ref.df, then we just ignore it.

Comment: `pearfromphina` do you match with `pearChina` in ref.df.  IF i check your expected,  it is showed along with the pearsJapan row i.e. 37 5, which are differet

Comment: @akrun yes! 0 to 1 letter difference is acceptable

Comment: Can you please check your expected.  `pearsJapan      5     11     37     5`  the `37 5` is from `pearfromphina`

Comment: I understsand your point, but you are categorizing it with Japan instead of china.  I see it more commonality with china (`phina`)

Comment: @ that's a typo sorry! edited.

Comment: In that case, I have a solution, but I am afraid that this may not work in your original case

Comment: Errr... posted it as answer and I will set it as the solution. I think you have spend enough time on it! Thank you so much!

Comment: It's okay.  I am not confident that it works for your other dataset